# Well-defined functor of triangulated category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $F \colon D \to D'$ be a morphism of triangulated categories, $S$ a multiplicative system compatible with triangulated structure of $D$.

> Supposing the colimits below exist, [Lemma 13.14.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05S7) defines a morphism
> $$
>   RF(X)
>   = \mathop{\mathrm{colim}}\limits_{s \colon X \to X'} F(X')
>   \longrightarrow RF(Y)
>   = \mathop{\mathrm{colim}}_{s' \colon Y \to Y'} F(Y')
> $$
> where we index over morphisms of $S$ out of $X,Y$ respectively.

The way this is defined uses MS2 of a multiplicative system.  It claims that independence follows from MS3 of a [multiplicative system](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VB).

I don't see exactly why this is true.  May someone elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

This is my attempt.

---

Take another choice via MS2
$$X' \rightarrow Y'', Y \rightarrow Y''$$
Then we can apply MS2 again to $(Y \rightarrow Y', Y\rightarrow Y'')$ given some $Z$. Then we obersve 
$$X \rightarrow X ' \rightarrow Y' \rightarrow Z$$
is same as 
$$X \rightarrow X'  \rightarrow Y'' \rightarrow Z$$

---

Now apply MS3 to the two morphisms $X ' \rightarrow Z$ which passes thorugh $Y', Y''$ respectively. We construct
$$Z \rightarrow Z'$$
a morphism in $S$. Now observe that we have constructed a comutative diagram in $S$ involving $(Y',Y'', Z, Z')$, this commutativity  implies that 
such that both possible maps $FX' \rightarrow RFY$ conincide by definition of $RFY$.